# Railscast 197, part 2: How to remove a group of fields in Rails 3?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms

I'm constructing a form in Rails 3, following the instructions in this video: http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2.

My form has one major difference from the form in the video: instead of being able to remove one field on the form, I'd like to be able to remove a group of fields from the form. This group contains the following fields: "number of people", "gender", "ethnicity", "age". I was able to remove this group of fields using the checkbox in part 1 of this video series, but since I added the jquery functionality, it hasn't worked.

Any suggestions?

**new.html.erb**

```
<%= f.fields_for :audiences do |builder| %>
<div class="audiencefields">

<%= builder.hidden_field :_destroy %>
<%= link_to_function "remove", "remove_fields(this)" %>
<p>
    <%= builder.label :number_of_people %><br />
    <%= builder.text_field :number_of_people %>
</p>
<p>
    <%= builder.label :gender %><br />
    <%= builder.text_field :gender %>
</p>
<p>
    <%= builder.label :ethnicity %><br />
    <%= builder.text_field :ethnicity %>
</p>
<p>
    <%= builder.label :age %><br />
    <%= builder.text_field :age %>
</p>
</div>
<% end %>
```

**application.js**

```
function remove_fields (link) {
        $(link).previous("input[type=hidden]").value = "1";
        $(link).up(".audiencefields").hide();
    }
```

Comment: I think you have to initially create the elements with style='display:none',  then .show() them when the page is loaded,  then your .hide() would work.

Comment: My suggestion would be to load it in Firefox with Firebug (an addon) to see if you get any errors in the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spent a while trying to figure this out, but couldn't find a solution since this railscast seems to be out of date for Rails 3. I ended up installing the Nested Form gem, and it works beautifully: https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have a problem with your jQuery try http://api.jquery.com to look up some of the functions.  I think you may be looking for

```
$(link).prev("input[type=hidden]").val = "1"
$(link).slideUp("audiencefields")
```

or something similar.  You may be looking for $(link).prev().css("hidden",true).  Not exactly sure, but it is possible.  Check firebug to make sure all the methods you used are part of jQuery.

Also, make sure all jQuery is in $(document).ready(); or it may not work.